# pandas row manipulation - If startwith keyword found - append row to end of previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a question regarding text file handling. My text file prints as one column.  The column has data scattered throughout the rows and visually looks great & somewhat uniform however, still just one column. Ultimately, I'd like to append the row where the keyword is found to the end of the top previous row until data is one long row.  Then I'll use str.split() to cut up sections into columns as I need.

In Excel (code below-Top) I took this same text file and removed headers, aligned left, and performed searches for keywords.  When found, Excel has a nice feature called offset where you can place or append the cell value basically anywhere using this offset(x,y).value from the active-cell start position. Once done, I would delete the row. This allowed my to get the data into a tabular column format that I could work with.

What I Need:
The below Python code will cycle down through each row looking for the keyword 'Address:'. This part of the code works. Once it finds the keyword, the next line should append the row to the end of the previous row. This is where my problem is. I can not find a way to get the active row number into a variable so I can use in place of the word [index] for the active row. Or [index-1] for the previous row.

Excel Code of similar task

```
Do
    Set Rng = WorkRng.Find("Address", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Offset(-1, 2).Value = Rng.Value
        Rng.Value = ""
    End If
Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing
```

Python Equivalent

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series


file = {'Test': ['Last Name: Nobody','First Name: Tommy','Address: 1234 West Juniper St.','Fav 
Toy', 'Notes','Time Slot' ] }

df = pd.DataFrame(file)

                             Test
0               Last Name: Nobody
1               First Name: Tommy
2  Address: 1234 West Juniper St.
3                         Fav Toy
4                           Notes
5                       Time Slot
```

I've tried the following:

```
for line in df.Test:
    if line.startswith('Address:'):
        df.loc[[index-1],:].values = df.loc[index-1].values + ' ' + df.loc[index].values        
            Line above does not work with index statement
    else:
        pass


# df.loc[[1],:] = df.loc[1].values + ' ' + df.loc[2].values  # copies row 2 at the end of row 1, 
                                                             # works with static row numbers only
# df.drop([2,0], inplace=True)  # Deletes row from df
```

**Expected output:**

```
                                               Test
0                                 Last Name: Nobody
1  First Name: Tommy Address: 1234 West Juniper St.
2                    Address: 1234 West Juniper St.
3                                           Fav Toy
4                                             Notes
5                                         Time Slot
```

I am trying to wrap my head around the entire series vectorization approach but still stuck trying loops that I'm semi familiar with. If there is a way to achieve this please point me in the right direction.

As always, I appreciate your time and your knowledge. Please let me know if you can help with this issue.

Thank You,

Comment: IIUC, you want to concat the row which starts with `Address` with its previous `row`, right?

Comment: yes, basically the row where 'Address:" is found will be combined (at the end) of the previous row.  I hope this answers what you are asking?

Comment: I guess the issue is I can not use static number in the row copy statement. There are 1000+ rows with the 'Address:' they are all uniform like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) on `Test` then use [`Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) to create a boolean mask, then use boolean indexing with this mask to update the values in `Test` column:

```
s = df['Test'].shift(-1)
m = s.str.startswith('Address', na=False)
df.loc[m, 'Test'] += (' ' + s[m])
```

Result:

```
                                              Test
0                                 Last Name: Nobody
1  First Name: Tommy Address: 1234 West Juniper St.
2                    Address: 1234 West Juniper St.
3                                           Fav Toy
4                                             Notes
5                                         Time Slot
```

Comment: Shubham, I thank you once again.  However before I let you go, I need to delete the original 'Address" line after the concat.  Based on what you have here could this work? df.drop([m,s], inplace=True), #where 'm' is the original line with Address and 's' is the column identifier?

Comment: Sorry, I was stressing on the concat portion of this project and didn't finish with the final delete original row.

Comment: @Boomer i guess you can filter the rows using `df = df[~df['Test'].str.startswith('Address')]` or better `df = df[~m.shift(fill_value=False)]`

Comment: ha ha ha... I totally was rolled up into your variable usage (How cool it is!!!) and was thinking that was the way to delete.  Your delete line is what I have been using for the headers on the text file.  Tunnel thinking.....I need to open my mind.  Your Unbelievable Shubham!!!  Thanks as always!!!!

Comment: happy coding :) @Boomer