# If row in dataframe starts with keyword, concat it with the row above

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, startswith

I have a question similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637504/pandas-row-manipulation-if-startwith-keyword-found-append-row-to-end-of-prev) but I have not been able to break through it.

I have a DataFrame structured like this:

```
0 inner join xx
1 on xx
2 and xx
3 and yy
4 and aa
5 inner join zz
```

I am trying to append the rows that start with 'and' to the previous row, resulting in something that looks like this:

```
0 inner join xx
1 on xx and xx and yy and aa
2 inner join zz
```

Later, I will then do the same thing with the 'on' keyword.

This is the code that I have so far. It works, but only appends it one time. Leaving me with an extra 'and' keyword:

```
for row in df:
     s = df['join'].shift(-1)
     m = s.str.startswith('and', na=False)
     df.loc[m, 'join'] += (' ' + s[m])
```

Comment: "I am trying to append the rows that start with 'and' to the previous row" -- shouldn't your result be in 3 lines, with the second line being `on xx and xx and yy and aa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`+`apply`:

```
(df.groupby((~df['join'].str.startswith('and ')).cumsum())
   ['join'].apply(' '.join)
)
```

output:

```
join
1                 inner join xx
2    on xx and xx and yy and aa
3                 inner join zz
Name: join, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a simple `for` loop:

```py
result = []
for j in df['join']:
    if j.startswith('and') and len(result) > 0:
        result[-1] += ' ' + j
    else:
        result.append(j)
```