# Looping over dataframe only returns one column

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, append

I have a dataframe formatted like this:

```
index   join             file
0       inner join         a
1       on xxx             a
2       inner join on yyy  b
3       left join          c
```

I am running a loop to append rows that start with "on" or "and" to the row above. Like this:

```
result = []
for j in df['join']:
    if j.startswith('and') and len(result) > 0:
        result[-1] += ' ' + j
    elif j.startswith('on') and len(result) > 0:
    result[-1] += ' ' + j
    else:
        result.append(j)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

The loop is running correctly and returning this:

```
index   join             
0       inner join on xxx  
1       inner join on yyy  
2       left join
```

However, the loop is not bringing in the "file" field. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: you are iterating on one column `for j in df['join']:`  use `for ind, row, in df.iterrows():`

Comment: Is this for an assignment? I'm pretty sure I saw something similar recently.

Comment: Found it: [If row in dataframe starts with keyword, append it to the row above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835198/if-row-in-dataframe-starts-with-keyword-append-it-to-the-row-above)

Comment: Not for an assignment, I'm just not good at python - also, if i'm not using the site correctly please let me know.

Comment: Well, the rule of thumb is that you should avoid doing loops in pandas. Whenever possible use `groupby` or vectorial operations. Let me know if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68847487/16343464) suits your need.

Comment: That's good to know, I was thinking that too but I wasn't sure how to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check rows not starting with "on" and apply a `cumsum` to group those starting with "on" with the previous row. Finally group and join:

```
(df.groupby((~df['join'].str.startswith('on ')).cumsum())
   ['join'].apply(' '.join)
   .reset_index(drop=True) # optional, to have index starting with 0
)
```

output:

```
join
0    inner join on xxx
1    inner join on yyy
2            left join
Name: join, dtype: object
```

To apply on all columns, use `agg`:

```
(df.groupby((~df['join'].str.startswith('on ')).cumsum())
   .agg(' '.join)
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
                join file
0  inner join on xxx  a a
1  inner join on yyy    b
2          left join    c
```

You can even apply different operations per column:

```
(df.groupby((~df['join'].str.startswith('on ')).cumsum())
   .agg({'join': ' '.join, 'file': 'first'})
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
                join file
0  inner join on xxx    a
1  inner join on yyy    b
2          left join    c
```